# How to use a dynamic library in a Visual C++ Android Application

Tags: android, c++, dynamic-library

I am trying to create a simple Visual C++ Native Activity Application (Android) that uses a dynamic shared library (.so). It seems to be a common thing, but I still can't find any samples for this. Microsoft provides the [TwoLibs sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/twolibs-android-library-6396e5c4), which is somewhat similar, but there the library is called from Java code. I need to do this in C++.

I tried to make a native activity and adding a reference to the shared library project. [image: Using shared library] 
It compiles fine, but when I run it, the program crashes. It doesn't even matter whether I call any functions from the library.

When I use a static library it doesn't crash.

I have also tried to add a compiled .so library to the list of dependencies wiwth the same success:
[image]

Could somebody explain me how this is supposed to be done?